# Meteor - Publications causing long loading time

Tags: meteor

I am trying to make a fairly big meteor app, and I noticed that it has gotten slower over the past few days and I read on the meteor forum that publications can cause slow loading times.  After I refresh the page when making a change in the application itself (code change), it usually takes between 1-2 minutes for a single change.  Is there anything wrong with my publications?  Although, when the page is loaded, and I reload it loads up really fast.

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish('notes', function () {
    return Notes.find()
  });
  Meteor.publish('users', function () {
    return Meteor.users.find()
  });
  Meteor.publish("user", function(){
    return Meteor.user()
  })
  Meteor.publish('notes-newest', function () {
    return Notes.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 10});
  });
}
```

document example:

```
let noteInfo = { title, subject, description, imageURL, userId, userEmail, createdAt }
let title = this.refs.title.value;
let subject = this.refs.subject.value;
let description = this.refs.description.value;
let allUrls = [this.refs.imageURL.value].concat(this.state.urls);
let imageURL = allUrls.filter(function(entry) { return entry.trim() != ''; });
let userId = Meteor.userId();
let userEmail = Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
let createdAt = Date.parse(new Date());
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad performance tuning question. You haven't told us how many documents are in your collections or how large these documents are. Some possible issues:

You are *over-publishing* either by publishing too many documents or because your documents are too big. For example when you do:

```
Meteor.publish('notes', function () {
  return Notes.find()
});
```

If there are 100,000 Notes documents at 100 bytes each then that's 10 MB that needs to go over the network to the client. This is also the case if there are 1,000 notes documents at 10KB each.

**Solution:** Limit the number of documents with `limit` and/or reduce the number of fields transmitted with `fields`:

```
Meteor.publish('notes', function () {
  return Notes.find({},{ limit: 100, fields: { key1: 1, key2: 1 }});
});
```

Your collection is missing one or more indexes. When you do:

```
Meteor.publish('notes-newest', function () {
  return Notes.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 10});
});
```

if there are 1M notes documents but there is no index on the `createdAt` key then this will be terribly slow.

**Solution:** Adding an [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) on the `createdAt` key will make such a publication much faster.

You have an *invalid publication*.

```
Meteor.publish("user", function(){
  return Meteor.user();
})
```

Is invalid because `Meteor.user()` is not a *cursor* and a publication must return either a cursor or an array of cursors. It is also *redundant* because `Meteor.user()` is automatically available on the client, albeit it doesn't include all the keys.

**Solution:** Remove this unnecessary publication altogether. If you want to publish some of the keys that are not available on the client for the current user you can do so as follows:

```
Meteor.publish("user", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId,{fields: {services: 1, emails: 1, profile: 1}})
});
```

Comment: Sorry for being too broad about my situation.  My total app folder size is around 180mb and only has around 20 documents in the notes collection.  I am just trying to develop a working website for now so I will add in the limit on the publication when I have a finished product. I also added in an example of a document in one of my collections(not sure where they are stored in the app to make it, so can't check the size).

Answer (score 1):

> After I refresh the page when making a change, it usually takes between 1-2 minutes for a single change. Is there anything wrong with my publications? Although, when the page is loaded, and I reload it loads up really fast.

What does this mean? Do you mean when you change the code of your website, it takes 1-2 minutes for your changes to appear in a newly loaded page? That's to be expected: it takes time for Meteor to rebuild your application. Watch the terminal for the progress.

Using lots of packages and external code will slow down building. The speed of compilation is unrelated to your end user's experience.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be slow but occasionally it loads pretty fast around 5-10 seconds.  But the majority of the time it takes 1-2 minutes.

Comment: "it loads pretty fast around 5-10 seconds." —This occurs when you only modify the CSS. If you modify code on the server side, it will take 1-2 minutes. If you modify code that is only loaded on the client, it may take as little as 10s and as long as 2 minutes. This behavior is by design. There are no other solutions to your question.

Comment: Suffice it to say, your question doesn't really state the problem you're experiencing in a way that's clear to other commenters. Your problem is slow build times in the app, it has nothing to do with publications. Other than using less code, there is no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I do with my meteor projects is that I send specific fields "profile.name" etc. I've also used collection.createIndex({}) which creates an index and inside it and you could put your sort in which is created on server startup and works well with your collection.find.sort. I think limiting your notes would be quite essential as you have a limit on one and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. At that time I checked with kadira (formerly still opensource but now it is not). Source code at [kadira on github](https://github.com/meteorhacks/kadira), but service is gone [kadira.io](https://kadira.io/)

The problem is in pubication and subscribtion. When client request subscribtions, he opens up some kind of "connection" - i say that, and it applies to others who call the same publication. imagine how many connections are formed. 
where the same data accessed by many people must server side must request data to mongodb, that same to all of number of such connections. This is what makes it slow.

Finally I added [redis.io](https://redis.io/).

```
meteor npm install --save redis
meteor npm install --save hiredis
```

On server side :

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";

var redis = require("redis");
var clientRedis = redis.createClient({
    host: "YOURREDIS_IP",
    port: "YOURREDIS_PORT"
});
clientRedis.setSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(clientRedis.set);
clientRedis.getSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(clientRedis.get);

setRedis_Object = function (keyREDIS, timeRefresh, valueREDIS) {
    return clientRedis.setSync(keyREDIS + moment(new Date()).format(timeRefresh), JSON.stringify(valueREDIS));
};

getRedis_Object = function (keyREDIS, timeRefresh) {
    return JSON.parse(clientRedis.getSync(keyREDIS + moment(new Date()).format(timeRefresh)));
};

Meteor.methods({
    getRedis_YOURCOLLECTIONS: function(timeRefresh) {
         var data = getRedis_Object(getRedis_YOURCOLLECTIONS, timeRefresh);
         if (data != null) {
              return data;
         } else {
              var data = YOURCOLLECTIONS.find().fetch();
              setRedis_Object(key, timeRefresh, data);
              return data
         }
    },
});
```

On Client Side

```
  Meteor.call("getRedis_YOURCOLLECTIONS", "YYYYMMDD", function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
          console.log(error);
      } else {
          Session.set("getRedis_YOURCOLLECTIONS", result);
      }
  });
```

After i am add this REDIS consumtion Memory and CPU on server low, and app more Fast. I hope its work for you. Thanks

Comment: Wow thats great! Where did you install your redis and how did you store data into the redis? Thanks

Comment: Best way difference server with database, but on local network with server side client. 
I have use Mongodb and Redis with DOCKER. its work well. 

redis is  in-memory data structure store, as you can see "setRedis_Object" is function to store data to redis key.